# Query on im.save in PIL python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am using `im.load()` to get the pixels of ORIGINAL_IMAGE. Subsequently, I save it

I see that whatever is saved is different from what I wanted to save -

This is a code snippet and output that will highlight my issue -

Snippet:

```
im = Image.open(ORIGINAL_IMAGE)
dup_im = im.copy()
pix = dup_im.load() 
dup_im.save(DUP_IMAGE)
saved_im = Image.open(DUP_IMAGE)
saved_pix = saved_im.load()

for i in range(10):
        print  pix[0, i], " : ", saved_pix[0, i]
```

Output of the print -

BEFORE SAVING : AFTER SAVING

```
$ python test.py 
162  :  162
162  :  162
162  :  163
162  :  163
162  :  163
164  :  162
160  :  161
159  :  160
155  :  153
155  :  155
$
```

Details about my Python version -

```
$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
```

Any idea why the two fields (pixels before and after saving) aren't the same?

Answer (score 6):

I can recreate this when loading a JPG and saving it as JPG again. The pixel data is equal when saving it as bitmap though. As JPG is a lossy image format, the save causes a re-encoding, thus changing the pixel data.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you read an image and save it afterwards (without changing it)?